# variable scope when programmatically assigning python class attributes

Tags: python, scope

### **ANSWER AT THE END**

I am trying to monkey patch a class with attributes that are assigned programatically, but I am running into a variable scope problem that I don't know how to solve.  See the code below:

```
class my_obj_class:
    pass
my_obj = my_obj_class()

letters = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]

for l in letters:
    for n in numbers:
        attribute_name = "print_" + l + str(n)

        def print_ln(self):
            print(l, n)

        setattr(my_obj_class, attribute_name, print_ln)

my_obj.print_a1()
l, n = "c", 3
my_obj.print_a1()
```

prints:

```
b 2
c 3
```

Obviously this isn't working the right way (print_a1 always prints "a1") because the print_ln is printing the variables l and n which are changing in the for loop and each attribute is using the same two variables.  I can't seem to conceive how to do this so that print_a1 always prints "a1" and not a value of a variable other than to hard code each attribute, which I am obviously trying not to do.

---

**ANSWER**

Yes, thanks for the comments, the answer is closures, which are new to me.  The for working loop is below:

```
for l in letters:
    for n in numbers:
        attribute_name = "print_" + l + str(n)

        def print_ln(l, n):
            def printer(self):
                print(l, n)
            return printer

        setattr(my_obj_class, attribute_name, print_ln(l, n))
```

Comment: Where's the `print_a1()` function?

Comment: you have to surround your functions with a closure

Comment: shouldn't you add the attributes to the instance `my_obj` instead of the class `my_obj_class`?

Comment: the print a1 function is defined in the for loops. l = 'a', n = 1, attribute_name = "print_" + l + str(n) --> print_a1, which is then added to the class with setattr

Comment: @hiro - that depends on what you want to do.  Since I want all future instances to have these variables I add it to the class

Comment: @VinceWest: if you do not have an `__init__` function that sets them to a default value there is really no point in doing that. or do you mean to add member functions?

Comment: @hiro, the real working example is significantly more complicated.  This was just an MVCE, but yes it is to add member functions (not variables)